# Problems with AutoCompletation TextField in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, autocomplete, textfield, controlsfx

I hava a problem with **AutocompletionText**.
I make a TextField where it's possible to have dynamic suggestions.

```
switch(hairPossibility.get(observable.getValue().intValue()).toString()){
    case ("length"):{
        questionCanBeChoosenArray.clear();
        questionCanBeChoosenArray.addAll(Arrays.asList("Suggestion1", "Suggestion2"));
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion((TextField) settingQuestionForSticker, questionCanBeChoosenArray);
        break;
    }
    case ("color"):{
        questionCanBeChoosenArray.clear();
        questionCanBeChoosenArray.addAll(Arrays.asList("Suggestion3", "Suggestion4"));
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion((TextField) settingQuestionForSticker, questionCanBeChoosenArray);
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I first click on length value in the ComboBox, in the TextField settingQuestionForSticker i see **Suggestion1** and **Suggestion2** (all right), but when I choose "color" in the combobox I would like to see only **Suggestion3** and **Suggestion4**, instead of Suggestion **#1, #2, #3 and #4.**

I used Autocompletion method said in ControlsFX and as TextField the JFX one.

Comment: Can you show more context for your code? It's not at all clear where you are executing this.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/melmello/IndovinaChi/blob/FirstBrench-15/01/16/src/sample/Client/ClientClass/ClientGameController.java)

I give you the whole file where you can understand everything.
The method where you can find the problem is: comboBoxInitialization()

Comment: Did you solve this? I also have same problem?

Comment: No Zcon.. I haven't found a solution sorry